# Ns2 802.11p simulation parameters of propagation model

Tags: ns2, sumo, 802.11p

Im using this tcl of 802.11p, provided by [Knud Larsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4491743/knud-larsen)

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Qxe_ydqwm-CXOQz8CM2Z1QJ2owMvNiw7

What I want to know is how can I calculate the coverage radius of each node or how can I change the default value to something around 50-100m, what parameters do I need to change and what formula and propagation model does ns2 uses to calculate that.
I have moved the values of gamma from 2.0 to 5.0 and I have noticed that the coverage radius has decrease but I want to be able to know the exact distance.
Also the value of Pt inside that tcl is given en mW?

Comment: Pt value can be set in mW : `Phy/WirelessPhy set Pt_ 0.2818` (equalizes 250m) ... or distance :  `Phy/WirelessPhy set Pt_ 7.214e-3 ;# 100m` ... ( 50meters is `1.33826e-3` ).

Comment: Ok but how can I calculate the values you're giving me, do you have a formula that depends of the propagation model or what is the formula? Also if I want to put for example 100mw in Pt do I put 100 or 0.1?

Comment: I looked at the 3000 simulations `grep Pt *` to find the examples. Not quite clear if e.g. 0.2818 was mW or W. Contradicting explanations in the examples. Please see  https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=ns2+set+Pt+mW .... **ex** http://mailman.isi.edu/pipermail/ns-users/2005-March/048467.html ... **ex2** (formula) https://www.researchgate.net/post/In_NS2_How_to_find_Pr_value_with_respect_to_distance_for_TwoRayGround_Propagation_model

Comment: See **ex2** ...

Comment: But I believe I have the Nakagami propagation model in the 802.11p you provided me or what propagation model do I use in that tcl, or the formulas are the same for that matter?

Comment: Search https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=ns2+set+Pt+mW+nakagami .... **ex** https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a62a/e2e7737da53119ea3485a892bbf2dff4f7b3.pdf